# UITableViewCells of different heights place their accessoryViews at different X positions

Tags: iphone, uikit, uitableview

My app has some table cells that vary in height. The cells can also have a `UIButton` set to be a detail disclosure button (round, blue with arrow) as their accessory view.

Depending on the height of the cell, the accessory view is positioned differently. At first I thought it was my layout code for my cell that was causing the problem, so I set up a quick independent test that uses vanilla `UITableCells` to remove the possibility that it could be my fault.

I set up a view in interface builder, and just added a view table cells to the view, set their heights to different values and then added a detail disclosure button to each. Nothing more, nothing less.

This is what I see:

[UITableViewCells with different x values http://jasarien.com/jing/accessoryView_x_difference.png](http://jasarien.com/jing/accessoryView_x_difference.png)

I added the size guides (thanks to [Xscope](http://iconfactory.com/software/xscope)) so you can see the difference in the accessory view x positions.

The heights are:

- top 37px
- mid 68px
- bottom 44px (default, untouched height)

If I increase the height any heigher than 68px the accessory view doesn't move any further to the left.

Is this a bug? Is there any way I can prevent this from happening?

Here's the test project to reproduce.

[TableViewCellHeightsTest.zip](http://jasarien.com/downloads/TableViewCellHeightsTest.zip)

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce this in iPhone SDK 3.0. Works fine here. Could you upload the independent test project, so I can download and test it?

Comment: I've added a link in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the same problem when I downloaded your file. Instead of setting the detail disclosure buttons manually and assigning them to cells as outlets, delete all disclosure indicators and try setting them this way instead:

[image]

Comment: Yes, I did notice that after you said you weren't seeing the issue. However, in my code the disclosure buttons are being created programatically and set as the cell's accessory view, so I was trying to replicate that in interface builder. I guess I overlooked the simplicity of just setting the cell's accessory type to detail disclosure and then setting it's action...

Comment: This is a very vexing problem. I have the same issue, setting all my cell code programmatically, and getting different positions for the indicators based on the cell height.

Answer (score 2):

Note: I set the background color of the content view to blue for ease of view.

[image]

*Figure 1 (accessory view height is 17.0)*

I was facing this problem and had the luxury of 2 colleagues helping me figure out the cause.

We find out that when using the default `UITableViewCell` (In my case, of style `UITableViewCellStyleDefault` though I believe it applies to all other styles), if your accessory view's height is anything above the magic number 16.0, the x position of the accessory view start to differ with the variance of height of the cell.

[image]

*Figure 2 (accessory view height is 16.0)*

My colleague had implemented a custom `UITableViewCell` and using subviews to layout content and was able to avoid this problem.

So you have 3 options:

- Restrict your accessory view's height to 16.0 and below.
- Use a custom `UITableViewCell` and layout your own content as subviews.
- Use the default accessory type.

[image]

*Figure 3 (default accessory type `UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton`)*

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue and fixed it by making the custom accessory view the same height as the cell.

Comment: Easily the best answer! Thanks!